# Swift 2: problems with UILabel position after the view is loaded

Tags: swift, uilabel

I have a little problem with an `ULlabel`. All I want to do is to move a `UIlabel` outside the view's bounds before it loads and then, when the view is loaded, show with a little animation.

So I have done this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)        
    self.lblQuestion.hidden = true
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.lblQuestion.center.y = -(self.view.bounds.height + 100)
}
```

It seems to be all ok because if I put a `print("\\(self.lblQuestion.center.y)")` in the `viewDidAppear` function I can see that the position is ok and the `UIlabel` is outside the bounds, like I want.

But if I wait 2 seconds and check with a new `print("\\(self.lblQuestion.center.y)")` inside a timer (for example) I see that the y position of the `UIlabel` is changed.

Does the `UIView` change its bounds after some event?

Can someone tell me what is happening, please?

Comment: A lot depends on what autolayout and constraints are doing.  I suggest starting by using Xcode's view debugging feature while the app is running.  You can capture the view hierarchy and inspect the size and placement of any view.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Phillip. I tryed to use debugging feature but the UILabel is outside the view, so i can't see her. I tried also to remove all constraints but never changed. The position of the UILabel, after 2 seconds, is the same. With or without constraints. I really can't believe it

Comment: I don't know if it will help but I believe there's a button on the view display that will let you see subviews outside the clipping region.  (I'm not on my dev system to check that at the moment.)

Comment: I just answered the same thing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193445/changing-an-autolayout-constrained-uiviews-frame-at-runtime-in-swift/39193543#39193543  Just combine that idea with an animation block.